# Creating a Bouyancy Force Generator

Tags: water, air, renewable-energy

How much energy is needed to maintain boiling water? (I'm assuming $1400~\rm W$). With that said, when air is added to an object to decrease its density, does the strength of its buoyant force increase? Can it be enough to create/maintain $1400~\rm W$?

Answer (score 1):

No.

At a temperature of $100^\circ~\rm C$ and a pressure of $1~\rm atm$, the heat of vaporization is $2257~\rm kJ/kg$. The more power you put in, the faster the water boils. It also generally decreases with higher temperatures and increases with higher pressures.

If this water vapor is used to displace water in an object, then yes, its buoyant force increases. But the work done by this extra buoyant force is always less than the energy required to vaporize the water, so you can't use this as any sort of perpetual motion device. If you put in $1400~\rm W$, whatever you get out will be less than $1400~\rm W$.

Comment: What if it's used as "reverse gravity"? I've seen devices that work off of weighted rocks, and after they just lift the rocks and rest them to start it over again. In this current setting, if air is created 1 foot below sea level, your not going to make much on the way back up. But at 100ft, 500ft, you can create much more. The amount of energy needed to create the air hasn't changed. It's not perpetual because water is your catalyst, and there is an abundance of that stuff around.

Comment: @JustinShearer As the depth increases, the pressure increases, and so too does the heat of vaporization. So, yes, the amount of energy required to create the water vapor has changed. What's more, the higher pressure means that the vapor is created at a higher density, so you get less buoyancy for a given quantity of gas.

Comment: @JustinShearer You can add whatever variables you like. Fundamentally the first law of thermodynamics says you can only get back at most what you put in. And the second law of thermodynamics says even that is impossible. No loopholes.

Comment: Thank you. Knowing that the deeper you go, the more energy is required, is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you for not throwing the "perpetual motion is impossible" as the first answer. I'll always try to find a way to make a more effective/efficient generator, and without your help, I couldn't move on. Thanks again!

Comment: @JustinShearer It *is* impossible, though. You can't get energy out of something without putting at least as much energy in. Try not to spend *too* much time on it.

Comment: Everything was impossible until it wasn't. I guess I'm looking for ways to use the abundance of natural things to create energy at low cost. Coal burns, heats water, spins turbine. Water heats up, turns to hydrogen, creates immense power in explosion. Harnessing a lightning bolt. I'm determined to figure something out that reduces our carbon footprint.

Comment: @JustinShearer I don't say it's impossible because we don't know how. The laws of physics tell us, unambiguously, that it is impossible. Which means any idea you come up with will always be refuted by the laws of physics. If you want to believe that the laws of physics are *wrong*, that's your prerogative, but asking "does this work under the laws of physics" for any device of this kind will always have the same answer.